# file as input for script when executing the script

Tags: linux

I want to give a file as input while executing the script

For example i have the code:

```
while read line    
do 

done<xyz
```

while executing the script

```
$sh file.sh input.txt
```

the file input.txt should go as input in the place of `xyz` for the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$1` to get the parameter:

```
while read line    
do 
  ...

done < "$1"
```

`$1` will contain the first parameter you give to the script.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash
echo "I have been given this parameter --> $1"

$ ./a hello
I have been given this parameter --> hello
```

Comment: k thanq so much sir for your advice